# Why can't I install this downloaded APK?

Tags: apk

I downloaded an APK and when I try to install it, the "install" button is completely unresponsive.

I have gone into the settings and enabled "Unknown sources" in the security section.

Is there something else I need to do?

I'm using a Galaxy S5 with Kitkat 4.4.2, unrooted.

Comment: Would you mind mentioning that .apk file? Is the 'Install' button greyed out?

Comment: No, the install isn't greyed out. Does it make a difference what APK file it is?

Comment: No. I want to whether that apk is compatible with the android version you are on.

Comment: It could be corrupt, it could be damaged in some way, what way are you clicking it to open it? It could have a script to only install on rooted devices / different version of Android. There's not enough information to go on here tbh.

Answer (score 57):

Disable your screen dimming app. :)

Some screen dimming apps work by overlaying the whole screen with a translucent window, and letting touch events pass through to the activity below, but for security reasons, you can't interact with system dialogs (such as the package installer) through another activity.

It sounds counter-intuitive, but it could be the cause. It's more likely than a corrupt APK file or a version incompatibility, either of which would cause an error message.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install it using `adb`. Download the Andorid SDK and then connect your phone to the PC via USB, make sure the USB Debugging option is ON under Developer Option in your phone settings.

Once you are done try to use these commands. `adb devices` to check the connection to your device and then if everything is OK try `adb install <filename>.apk`. Make sure you input the correct path to the file or simply copy the apk into `adb` directory.

`adb` usually resids into `adt-bundle-$version/sdk/platform-tools`

You can command prompt `cmd` in Windows or console in *nix based system.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Verify Apps in Security. If that didn't help, you could just **copy** the **apk** file to **/data/app/** and reboot the phone (as a temporary solution), also try Wiping the Dalvik Cache.

Comment: What?  There is no 'verify apps' in security.

Answer (score 0):

if you received a warning,then Google can and does block apps that can be damaging,and or have malicious code in them. Google can even remove apps after installing as well. Find and read their policy on installing apks from other sources.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  In my case, I am just trying to test an APK in the emulator.  My own APK that I developed - and getting this error!